# Index out of range when using lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I'm a little confused about lambda operators in Python right now. The following (working) code sorts a list of tuples after the number of occurrences of a tuples first element over the first elements of all tuples:

```
tuples = [(2, 1, 8, 4), (3, 4, 8, 1), (3, 8, 1, 4), (4, 1, 8, 3),
              (4, 8, 1, 3), (8, 8, 3, 1), (8, 1, 3, 4), (8, 4, 1, 3),
              (8, 4, 3, 1)]

temp = list(zip(*tuples))    
tuples.sort(key=lambda x: temp[0].count(x[0])
                ,reverse=True)

print(tuples)
```

However, if I now try to skip the creating of "temp", i.e write this:

```
tuples = [(2, 1, 8, 4), (3, 4, 8, 1), (3, 8, 1, 4), (4, 1, 8, 3),
              (4, 8, 1, 3), (8, 8, 3, 1), (8, 1, 3, 4), (8, 4, 1, 3),
              (8, 4, 3, 1)]

tuples.sort(key=lambda x: list(zip(*tuples))[0].count(x[0])
                ,reverse=True)

print(tuples)
```

It throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python-Programms\Sorting", line 6, in <module>
    ,reverse=True)
  File "E:\Python-Programms\Sorting", line 5, in <lambda>
    tuples.sort(key=lambda x: list(zip(*tuples)) [0].count(x[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why does this error occur?

Comment: I don't have any documentation text to back it up, but `sort` modifies its argument in-place, so accessing the list being modified inside the key function is probably undefined.

Comment: Sorting it in place or not, the size should remain the same. Why then, would `[0]` throw an out of bounds error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you used a vanilla function and printed the list while it is being sorted, you'll notice the list is cleared out during the sort operation (AFAIK this applies to CPython). There isn't an index zero for an empty list:

```
def f(x):
  print (tuples)
  return ...

tuples.sort(key=f ,reverse=True)

[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

A peek into the CPython source leaves us with a useful comment that explains this behaviour:

```c
static PyObject *
list_sort_impl(PyListObject *self, PyObject *keyfunc, int reverse)
{
    ...
    /* The list is temporarily made empty, so that mutations performed
     * by comparison functions can't affect the slice of memory we're
     * sorting (allowing mutations during sorting is a core-dump
     * factory, since ob_item may change).
     */
    ...
}
```

---

To your original problem, instead of calling `list.count` repeatedly, which is very inefficient, you can build a counter and then use that for sorting:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter([x[0] for x in tuples])
tuples.sort(key=lambda x: c[x[0]], reverse=True)
```

Comment: The fact that it's cleared is considered an implementation detail; attempting to inspect the list at all during a sort is considered undefined behavior, and different Python implementations may behave differently.

Answer (score 4):

The list

```
list(zip(*tuples))
```

in your `lambda` function is *not a constant one* - it evaluates *again and again* in every sorting step - every time when your `lambda` function is called.

1<sup>st</sup> sorting step is OK - the `lambda` function is exactly what you wanted. But then raises a problem.

The `tuples` list is during sorting in an *unstable state*, maybe empty, maybe something else - the sorting algorithm has freedom in it. Its only duty is so that the sorted list will be in the right state *after* performing the complete sort.

2<sup>nd</sup> sorting step evaluates the value of your `lambda` function on the basis of this *unstable* list - who knows its current value?

So using sorted list *itself* in the `key` function is not a very happy decision.